# Using Entity to syncronize scripts file with a database

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity

its possible I used Entity framework to read a folder, get somes sql scripts files and syncronize with my database? If I want to roolback some modifications or some error happens can I used entity to return the original snapshot database?

I want to use Entity only to manager and create historic changes of my database.

Thx.

Comment: This not something EF can do for you out-of-the-box. Use a batch file and sqlcmd to see how close you can get to meet all your requirements.